How can I efficiently move data from Databricks to Snowflake?
I’m going to explain you a real problem I'm facing in my job, related to the movement of data from Databricks in Delta format, to Snowflake (which we use as an exposure layer).
I work as a Data Engineer in a fairly large company. We have a batch of about 800 tables with daily loads, some with hourly loads. There is a team in charge of extracting the data from the different sources and loading it in our datalake in CSV. Some loads are incremental (insert/update), and some are full (insert overwrite). Our data movement strategy, orchestrated by Airflow, is basically as follows:
Data Movement Strategy Scheme
The problem comes in the cost of moving data from Curated to Snowflake with incremental loads. When there are some records to be inserted and others to be modified, we perform a merge with spark in Databricks. In the last step, we read only the last changes from our delta table in Curated, and perform another merge to the Snowflake table, and this is very expensive.
To reduce the cost, we have created external tables in Snowflake pointing to the Curated delta table. We don't want to expose the external tables because they are too slow for analytics, so, using Airflow we do an insert overwrite from the external table to a Snowflake managed table. This works perfect with full loads because there aren't large tables, but with the heavier ones, when we have an incremental load, the Snowflake warehouse takes forever to scan the external table, so it is even more expensive.
For those cases, we have thought of reading directly the CSV that we have stored in Raw with Snowflake, and, looking for the PKs, do a delete and an insert of those records directly in the internal table.
What would you do if you were in this situation? Can you think of any other solution to simplify the pipeline?
Maybe another out-of-the-box solution? I don’t know, I think I’m lost at this point…
I hope I have explained myself well, I will try to solve all the doubts you may have.

what if you split the larger files for external table.  Are they already splitted. ?

Have you considered using iceberg tables instead of delta tables? Snowflake iceberg tables is a similar performance as managed snowflake tables. Bonus is your not duplicating data.

You may want to try a small test with dynamic tables to replace the merge into Snowflake. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dynamic-tables-intro mentions that dynamic tables can provide a significant performance improvement with incremental processing.

If you are going to be moving your data through two different platforms this is always going to be relatively expensive. Assuming you can't move to a single platform, there are various options you could take, some of which you have mentioned. Only you can decide which one is the best for you based on your data volumes, cost, etc.

Generate the "final" dataset required by Snowflake in Databricks and load that into Snowflake - either as an complete reload or merge
Generate an "interim" dataset in Databricks, load that into a Snowflake staging layer (again either as a complete re-load or merge) and then load it into your final layer (complete re-load or merge)
Load the data from Raw into Snowflake and then process it through the standard layers i.e. replicating what you do in Databricks

Once you've decided on which is the best solution for you, there are probably ways to ensure that your solution is as performant as possible - but again that is likely to depend on data volumes, delta volumes, etc.
